# FB.Canvas.showFlashElement() not working

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-iframe, flashvars

I have a facebook app iframe which contains flash (wmode: window). The [FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) provides a [callback function](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#hide_flash_callback) to customize the hiding behaviour.

Without using this callback, the hiding and showing works perfectly. But when using it, my flash is not returning to visible. My logged params are ok. Apparently, Facebook adds "visibility:hidden;" to my Application selector and does not remove it properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in flash div

```
<style>
#MyFlashObjectID {
visibility: visible !important;
}
</style>
```